# Вывод текста по изогнутой линии в GDI+

Tags: delphi, gdi, gdi+

В общем хотелось сделать что-то типа бегущей по плавной синусоиде строки на GDI+ 
Но я так и не понял как там корректно можно поворачивать каждую следующую букву, чтобы текст получился по нужной кривой. Там можно крутить область вывода относительно какой-либо точки, а больше я ничего подходящего для этих целей не нашёл...
Неужели центр вращения двигать по синусоиде и для каждой буквы высчитывать касательную к ней для задания угла наклона? Всё равно какой-то бред получается, т.к. там вместе с наклоном следующего кадра наклоняется вся предыдущая картинка.

Comment: Может после того как покрутили область вывода и вывели текст, нужно вернуть все обратно?

Comment: Но это же двойные затраты, и так после каждого символа вращение холста, а тут ещё и назад! Сделаю пока через WinAPI с помощью CreateFont для каждого следующего символа. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934754/draw-rotate-multiline-text-with-gdi-and-gdi

Comment: По-моему "вращение холста" ничего не стоит по сравнению с CreateFont по затратам ресурсов. "Вращение" предполагает только задание новой матрицы трансформирования, которая в любом случае будет применяется к следующей операции рисования. По крайней мере в DirectX так и в обычном GDI, вроде, тоже так.

Comment: по хорошему, да, так и должно быть, но GDI это не DirectX. Это нужно потом будет отдельно тестировать, чтобы делать какие-то выводы о скорости

Comment: GDI+ и DirectX - это родственные технологии.